# Repeating a SQL INSERT query a particular number of times with an incremental value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a SQL query for inserting data into a table consisting of values for `StorageRowNo` and `StorageID`. The goal is to repeat this query a specified number of times with `StorageRowNo` increasing by 1 every time the query is repeated. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
INSERT [dbo].[StorageRow]
    SELECT StorageRowNo, StorageID
    FROM (VALUES (1, 2)) V (StorageRowNo, StorageID)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM [dbo].[StorageRow] C
                      WHERE C.StorageRowNo = V.StorageRowNo 
                        AND C.StorageID = V.StorageID);
```

Expected output would be something like this if the specified number were 3.

| StorageRowNo | StorageID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

Comment: Can you make it an `IDENTITY` column?

Answer (score 0):

use straight sql if you can

```
DECLARE @numRepeats INT = 10; -- number of times to repeat the query


INSERT [dbo].[StorageRow]
 SELECT V.StorageRowNo, V.StorageID
    FROM (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as StorageRowNo
                 ,2 as StorageID
           from master..spt_values
         ) V
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM [dbo].[StorageRow] C
                       WHERE C.StorageRowNo = V.StorageRowNo 
                         AND C.StorageID = V.StorageID);
       AND V.StorageRowNo<=@numRepeats
```